# Rounding float to next integer at .5

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, rounding

I thought `lroundf` would round my float to the next highest number at .5 steps. E.g. `1.5f` would be rounded to `2.0f`.

I tried, but my code tells me otherwise:

```
int roundUp = 1.5f;

NSLog(@"no round up: %d", roundUp);
NSLog(@"lroundf: %ld", lroundf(roundUp));
```

And my output is:

```
no round up: 1
lroundf: 1
```

How do I correctly round up my float?

Comment: First start by using a `float` (or `double`) instead of `int`.

Comment: ...*facepalm*... sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int rounded = lroundf(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",rounded);
int roundedUp = ceil(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedUp);
int roundedDown = floor(theFloat); NSLog(@"%d",roundedDown);
```

Comment: This would be more useful if the OP actually had `theFloat` instead of `theInt`.

Comment: He asked how to correctly round up the float. I assumed he did it right. Now I see he was wrong.